# Registered an array to JavaScript using C#

Tags: javascript

I want to plot multiple marker to a google map.

I have multiple address in the database without their longitude and langitude..

I caluculate the longitude and langitude of each address using google api..

Now I want to registered a JavaScript variable with the collection of address,longitute,langitude etc..

So, that I fetch that variable in JavaScript and map the multiple markers in Google map.

Need to Registered a JavaScript Variable like this in C#..

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create string array for geocode and message some thing like below. A working copy available http://deepumi.wordpress.com/tag/google-map-3-in-asp-net-c/

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var geocodes = new List<String>
     {
         " '40.756012, -73.972614' ",
         " '40.456012, -73.796087' ",
         " '40.456012, -73.456807' "
     };

    var geocodevalues = string.Join(",", geocodes.ToArray());

     var titles = new List<String>
     {
         " 'Google Map 3 Awesome !!!' ",
         " 'Made it very simple' ",
         " 'Google Rocks' "
     };

    var message = string.Join(",", titles.ToArray());

    ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("locationList", geocodevalues);

    ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("message", message);
 }
```